# How to attach Spring source for java 11

Tags: spring

I am having a difficult time attaching Spring 5.3.x source code in eclipse.
I tried multiple ways one of them was to add a source to Java build path. However, I am not able to find the spring 5.3.x source code itself.
I have searched the official spring site - https://spring.io/blog/2018/10/30/spring-boot-2-1-0
on git too https://github.com/spring-projects
none of them has source code.

Another was to Right-click on the project -> maven -> Download Sources. It started updating the project however I still don't see the source code.

[image]

Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: The sources should be resolved automatically. There is something wrong with your project or with eclipse settings. Unfortunately there is not enough information to help. Try to delete the project and import it again. If it doesn't help, try to do "mvn clean install" with your command-line and make sure that it is sucessful. Maybe there are some cyclic dependencies. Also check your jdk settings in "preferences". Make sure there are no errors, and that you are pointing to jdk not to jre. In general, make sure that there are no other errors, anywhere else, which you didn't notice.

Comment: The reason could also be in your project itself. Maybe it contains conficting dependency versions of "spring-security-core". Try to create another simple project, which contains "spring-security" libraries: if new simple project doesn't have this problem, then the problem is in your current project dependencies. If new simple project also has this problem, then there is something wrong with your eclipse configuration or plugins (see the previous comment)

Comment: You are right, I created a simple project which has spring security core, and for that simple project issue does not exist. The difference which I found is simple project is using jdk 1.8 and the main project is using jdk 11. Well, I try investigating it.

Comment: Your current java runtime in eclipse seems to be jdk8. Go to Eclipse -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs and switch to JDK11. Then delete the project and reimport it again.

There might be some other issues in your project, after you switch to JDK11, but in this case I would need more information, including your pom.xml.

Also, check your project with command-line: "mvn clean install". Make sure that it compiles successfully, before importing it to eclipse. You might need to change your JAVA_HOME to point to JDK11.

Comment: When i changed the parent version release from <version>2.4.3</version> to <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version> and as soon as build it. It could automatically download java doc and source and the problem got resolved. I again switched back to <version>2.4.3</version> and again I started facing the same problem.

Comment: 2.4.3 version might have some incompatible with JDK8 changes. Make sure you use JDK11 in eclipse and reimport the project. Before reimport make sure that it compiles successfully outside eclipse. Use "mvn clean install" with command-line. Make sure your JAVA_HOME points to JDK11 too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current java runtime in eclipse seems to be jdk8.

Go to `Eclipse -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs` and switch to JDK11.
Then delete the project and reimport it again.
There might be some other issues in your project, after you switch to JDK11, but in this case I would need more information, including your pom.xml.

Also, check your project outside the eclipse, with command-line: "mvn clean install". Make sure that it compiles successfully, before importing it to eclipse. Make sure your JAVA_HOME points to JDK11

Here is the example of pom.xml for JDK11 Spring Boot 2.4.2 project. Compare it with your own pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>skyglass</groupId>
    <artifactId>notepad</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>notepad</name>
    <description>Notepad demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

.....
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort man, Much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else helps, try to clean your local maven repository.

Deleting folder `m2/repository/org/springframework` should be enough